# Google Fusion Table Authentication: HTTP Error 400

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-fusion-tables

I tried out this python [example code](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/python) and received the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\rey\Documents\ProjectFolder\GoogleCharts\fusion.py", line 187, in <module>
    api_test.main()

  File "C:\Users\rey\Documents\ProjectFolder\GoogleCharts\fusion.py", line 55, in main
    serv_resp = urllib2.urlopen(serv_req)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I followed the instructions in the commented out section in the script to setup my authentication and think I have done the setup correctly.

To create the client ID, I have these settings:

```
Application type: Installed application

Installed application type: Other
```

When I run the script, the program prompts me for URL parameter. What am I supposed to enter for that? And where can I find more examples? The example that O have linked is the only up to date python example I've found so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, when prompt for the URL parameter, literally use the parameter of the URL after "code=". This is somewhat disappointing though, since I am looking for a way to automatically authenticate and create a fusion table from a local file that has all the info. Any suggestion?